# Reading Unity Dependency from class Library config

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using Unity for dependency Injection.I have created a config file in my services class library project where i have defined all the setting for unity.
In Web config i have following settings for unity.

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <unity configSource="assembly://authentication.Services/authentication/unity.config"/>
```

In class library i have defined unity.config.

I have created a static function inside the class library to read using settings.

```
public static T GetInstance<T>(string container, string name)
{
  Dictionary<string, IUnityContainer> Container = new Dictionary<string, IUnityContainer>();
  UnityConfigurationSection configs = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
  foreach (var config in configs.Containers)
  {
    var current = new UnityContainer();
    current.LoadConfiguration(config.Name);
    Container.Add(config.Name, current);
  }

  T service = Container[container].Resolve<T>(name);
  return service;
}
```

When i try to resolve dependency with unity compiler throw error unity.config is not defined.

> Visual studio throws exception  ConfigurationErrorsException: The
>   configSource attribute must be a relative physical path, so the '/'
>   character is not allowed.

**How can i read unity setting from unity.confiq file i have defined in the class library.**

Thanks

Comment: 1) Are you sure that you are defined `unity.config` file?
2) Are you sure that you always copy `unity.config 'during at build?
Well, your code works for me as well.

Comment: I have define unity.config in the class library .

Comment: I don't think you can reference a resource here, `unity.config` has to be a real file.